# How to animate the camera to the specific location inOpen street map(OSM) in android?

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I have used the below code to show the osm map.

```
    IMapController iMapController = map.getController();
    iMapController.setZoom(20);
    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(11.9534485,79.8201425);
    iMapController.setCenter(geoPoint);
```

**I want to animate the camera to the specific location as in google map.Is it possible to do ?**

Please suggest some ways to proceed.

Comment: 2 of the answers here are for the google library because you added the tag "openstreetmap" which is too broad, and in this case, unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Use below code:

```
  IMapController mapController;

  final GeoPoint myPoint1 = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
  mapController.setCenter(myPoint1);

  mapController.zoomTo(Integer.parseInt(15));
  map.getController().animateTo(myPoint1);
```

Answer (score -1):

onMapReady put there code to cemera animation of your given location

final LatLngBounds.Builder mapboundbuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

mapboundbuilder.include("YOUR LATLNG PAIR");

LatLngBounds tmpbnd = mapboundbuilder.build();

LatLng center = tmpbnd.getCenter();
            LatLng northEast = Consts.mappointmove(center, 709, 709);

```
        LatLng southWest = Consts.mappointmove(center, 709, 709);

        mapboundbuilder.include(southWest);

        mapboundbuilder.include(northEast);

        LatLngBounds bounds = mapboundbuilder.build();

       LatLng center = tmpbnd.getCenter();

        LatLng northEast = Consts.mappointmove(center, 709, 709);

        LatLng southWest = Consts.mappointmove(center, 709, 709);

        mapboundbuilder.include(southWest);

        mapboundbuilder.include(northEast);

        LatLngBounds bounds = mapboundbuilder.build();

        try {
            int width, height;
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            width = size.x;
            height = size.y - 250;
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, 100);
            googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is The Code for **animate the camera to the specific location** in the View of **satellite View**

```js
public class NewMap implements OnMapReadyCallback{
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map){

//Enter Your Specific Location Here

LatLng mySpecificLocation=new LatLng(11.9534485,79.8201425);

map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mySpecificLocation,13));

//This one for change the map view into Steet View
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

CameraPosition cameraPosition=CameraPosition.builder()
//this one takes map position into your specific location
.target(mySpecificLocation)
//this one for camera zooming option
.zoom(13)
.build();
//This one for animate camera
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPostion(camerapostion,2000,null));
}
}
```

Comment: This is for Google map not for OSM.